# Part two: speeddating object

Tags: java

```
public class Dating
{
// Note: this class has no instance variables!

/**
* Creates an empty Dating object so that you can call the methods
*/

public Dating()
{
// Empty constructor
}

 /**
 * Computes and returns the next year in which New Year's Day will
 * fall on the same day of the week as in a given year
 * @param theYear the given year
 * @return the next year in which New Year's day is the same day
 * of the week as in parameter theYear
 */
 public int newYears(int theYear)
 {
     // TO DO: write body of this method here
 }

/**
 * Computes and returns the Date on which Election Day will fall 
 * in the USA for a given year.
 *
 * NOTE: By law, Thanksgiving  Day is the first Tuesday after the first
 * Monday in November.
 *
 * @param year the year for which to compute the date of Election Day
 * @return the Date of Election Day for the specified year
 */
  public Date electionTime(int year)
 {
    INSERT CODE HERE
  }
```

I feel like I got the electionTime part correct but I am confused as in to where to begin for newYears. Any suggestions? I'm uncertain how to put together a code that would calculate not only when the date is but when it will happen again. I was not given a specific year to start with either.

Comment: So what do you want us to do?

Comment: That class has no instance variables!

Comment: Is this a homework problem? :P

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins they usually are aren't they? Lol! I don't want the answer because I will not learn that way. Most have you have been programming for years and I desperately want to learn. I've tried everything and have read countless textbooks but nothing helps like actual problems. The internet is full of assignments professors have put together so I'm trying to find the answers. But there really isn't anyone to check my work! :(

Comment: I think Code Review is better-suited for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * Computes and returns the next year in which New Year's Day will
 * fall on the same day of the week as in a given year.
 */
public int newYears(int year)
{
    // First, find out what day of the week it falls on in year X
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // create a calendar object
    calendar.set(year, 0, 1); // calendar.set([year], January, 1st)
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // store this value for later

    // The code between the curly braces below will be executed 30 times,
    // the first time i = 1, the second i = 2, third i = 3, etc...
    for(int i = 1; true; i++)
    {
        calendar.set(year + i, 0, 1); // set the calendar to the next year
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == day) // compare to the value we stored earlier, and if it's the same day...
        {
            return year + i; // we have the correct year!
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay I'm going overboard here but I must follow the calling of my inner geek.

I took a for loop and looped through and ran a bunch of sequential years through the function, subtracted to find the difference, and got this table:

```
  in  |  out  |  difference
 2004    2009     5
 2005    2011     6
 2006    2012     6
 2007    2018     11
 2008    2013     5
 2009    2015     6
 2010    2016     6
 2011    2022     11
 2012    2017     5
 2013    2019     6
 2014    2020     6
 2015    2026     11
```

There's a very clear pattern that repeats every four years (because of leap year I suppose). Using this, we can write a sneaky/condensed version of this function:

```
public int sneakyNewYears(int year)
{
    int diff = year % 4;

    int add = -1;
    if(diff == 0) add = 5;
    if(diff == 1) add = 6;
    if(diff == 2) add = 6;
    if(diff == 3) add = 11;

    return year + add;
}
```

This works fine for 98.6% percent of years, but testing this 'sneaky' function against the working function shows that there are a few years that this doesn't work for, for some odd reason... These years: 1575, 1577, 1578, 1579, 1580, 1581, 1582, 1691, 1695, 1696, 1697, 1698, 1699, 1700, 1791, 1795, 1796, 1797, 1798, 1799, 1800, 1891, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899 and 1900.

Anyway.

Comment: It is beyond me how people do this so quickly and I spend countless hours fighting with myself. Any advice on how to pick this up any quicker?

Comment: That's a very difficult question to answer in 600 characters :) The best way to get good at anything, really, is to immerse yourself in the subject. Practice, set easy goals for yourself at first and make them more and more difficult. There are no easy roads to success. Eat, sleep and breathe code. Pretty soon it'll be falling out your ears :) I have a folder of literally hundreds of little programs I made when I was first learning. Oh yes, Stackoverflow and Google are your friend!

Comment: And one more thing... you should have a passion for it! See my updated answer. (And if my answer answers your question, be sure to click the check mark to the left of it :)

Comment: I want to thank you very much for your help! I was able to compile the rest of the code and run it without error! Which updated answer?

Comment: Oh! Wow, it had not updated until now! I hadn't even taken the time to notice that.